# Arrays and foreach loop - novice at work

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Would love someone's help please - learning PHP, my first language.

I can loop through a single array using **foreach**, but what if I want to get at 2 arrays? This is my example using darts players!

```
$nationality = array ('Green' => 'England', 'Dekker' => 'Holland','Bunting'=> 'England', 'Montgomery'=>'Scotland');

$ranking = array ('Green' => 4, 'Dekker' => 6,'Bunting'=> 1, 'Montgomery'=> 57);
```

Q: How do I utilise **foreach** to loop through both arrays and generate a sentence such as (array data in bold)"**Green** is from **England** and is ranked **4**."

Comment: You could post some code you have already, so we can tweak it. Welcome on SO!

Comment: Thank you so much @Prisoner! You put me on the path to working out how to do it with a multidimensional array too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$nationality = array ('Green' => 'England', 'Dekker' => 'Holland','Bunting'=> 'England', 'Montgomery'=>'Scotland');

$ranking = array ('Green' => 4, 'Dekker' => 6,'Bunting'=> 1, 'Montgomery'=> 57);

foreach($nationality as $player => $country){
    echo "{$player} is from {$country} and is ranked {$ranking[$player]}. ";
}
```

This will output:

> Green is from England and is ranked 4. Dekker is from Holland and is ranked 6. Bunting is from England and is ranked 1. Montgomery is from Scotland and is ranked 57.

Comment: To clarify: He uses the  current "$player" as index for the "$ranking". So both arrays use the same index which prints the correct output.

Comment: Thanks @Y U NO WORK, are you saying it could also be done using a different index for $ranking?

Comment: @simien, you could also look through `$ranking` instead of `$nationality`, as the keys for the data are the same.

Comment: I assumed there had to be a common key for this **foreach** to use both arrays? What if, say, `$ranking` had a different key?